# Spring Security - Able to return to login page after initial redirect to home page

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, groovy, spring-security

I'm trying to create an application that will allow the user only to have access to the login page while they are not logged in, with no access to anything else (minus resources). Once they are logged in, I would like them to not be able to access the login page until they log out, with access to all other pages. Right now, my service remembers me when I'm already logged in but it will still let me access the login page. When I attempt to identify the user at the login controller, the authentication is always null.

Note, I'm using:
Spring MVC 3
Hibernate 4
Groovy 2.1

Here's my login controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
String login(Model model, @RequestParam(value="account", required=false) String account, @RequestParam(value="uuid", required=false) String uuid, @RequestParam(value="message", required=false) String message) {
    addStatusAttribute(model, account, uuid, message)
    model.addAttribute("newUser", new User())
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication
    if (auth != null) {
        logger.info(auth.name)
    }
    else {
        logger.info(auth) // Always hits here
    }
    if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) && auth != null) {
        "forward:/home"
    }
    else {
        "login"
    }
```

Here's my security config:

```
<http auto-config="true">
            <intercept-url pattern ="/login**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/static/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
        always-use-default-target="true" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
    <remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource"
        user-service-ref="myUserDetailsManager"
        token-validity-seconds="864000"
        key="skyfury_key"/>
</http>
```

I don't think there are any problems in this, but here's my JSP form:

```
                    <form method="POST" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />">
                <input type="text" name="j_username" placeholder="Email" />
                <input type="password" name="j_password" placeholder="Password" />
                <label for="j_remember">Remember Me</label>
                <input id="j_remember" type='checkbox' name='_spring_security_remember_me' value="on" />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </form>
```

Please help if you can! I've been staring at this for too long!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your /login URL you are mapping to filters="none" which means that the SecurityContext and Authentication will not be available for that URL. Try changing your configuration as seen below:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern ="/login**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/home"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
        always-use-default-target="true" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
    <remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource"
        user-service-ref="myUserDetailsManager"
        token-validity-seconds="864000"
        key="skyfury_key"/>
</http>
```

You will notice I made three changes:

1. First I stated to [use-expressions="true"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-http-use-expressions). This allows you to use [SpEL in the access attribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/el-access.html). By allowing for SpEL you have more power in your configuration and can state that any user is allowed to access the resource with "permitAll". Using "permitAll" is different than the [filters="none"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-intercept-url-filters) in that Spring Security still operates on this request but will allow any user to access the request. This means that the SecurityContextHolder is populated for requests mapped to permitAll.
2. The second change is to modify the "/login" URL to be mapped to permitAll. Again this means that the SecurityContextHolder is populated for requests mapped to permitAll.
3. The last change is that the other access attributes were updated so that they work with the use-expressions="true" change. Specifically "ROLE_USER" will not work. Instead you must state "hasRole('ROLE_USER')" instead.

I would also consider using the following instead of accessing the Authentication directly. This ensures that you are not tightly coupled to Spring Security.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
String login(Principal principal, Model model, @RequestParam(value="account", required=false) String account, @RequestParam(value="uuid", required=false) String uuid, @RequestParam(value="message", required=false) String message) {
    ...

    logger.info(principal?.name)

    if (principal != null) {
        "forward:/home"
    }
    else {
        "/login"
    }
}
```

This works because Spring MVC will [automatically resolve the Principal](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments) to the value found in [HttpServletRequest.userPrincipal](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29). Since Spring Security replaces the HttpServletRequest.userPrincipal with the current Authentication object when the Authentication is not anonymous this works transparently for you.

Answer (score 0):

your login seems not well,As spring security Doc ,You should implement UserDetailsService,
instead of getting param and your login method must has just ModelMap and not any params,
see example :http://aykutakin.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/spring-security-spring-custom-authentication-provider/
for logout also you can invalidate session by

```
   <logout  delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true"
     logout-success-url="/login.do" />
```

however In many case it entirely depends on browser cache , and may not work well!
If you using session time out in webserver XML that is sufficient and don't worry about session destroy.